# Angular 2 material mat-select programmatically open/close

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-select

Does any one know how to programmatically open or close mat-select? As pert the api there are methods for open and close but don't know how to call those methods from component and there isn't any example showing that on site.

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to access these properties you need to identify the DOM element and access it with a `ViewChild`:

**component.html**

```xml
  <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

**component.ts**

```js
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect;
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  click() {
    this.mySelect.open();
  }
}
```

[View a working stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kc1uhi)

Comment: I am getting error: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: @SolomonRaja This will often happen if the `mat-select` isn't available in DOM. Make sure that any `.open()` calls are made after the view is initialized (won't be available in constructor, OnInit, etc.). Make sure there are no `*ngIf` or similar causing it to not be rendered in the DOM as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am even getting this error in the mentioned stackblitz example. Please help me if I am making any mistakes

Comment: @SolomonRaja Sorry, but I'm not seeing any issues across multiple browsers when running the default stackblitz. All I can think is trying to define `mySelect` as a MatSelect: `@ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: MatSelect;`

Answer (score 12):

Another approach, so as not to so tightly couple the material component to your typescript code would be to handle this all on the HTML side.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br/>
<button (click)="mySelect.toggle()">click</button>
```

I used `toggle()` on the "selected" answer to both open or close the panel, although you can substitute `open()` or `close()` calls depending on your needs.

The key piece seems to be that template variable (`#mySelect`) that I learned thanks to the answer that @zbagley provided.  I just kept tinkering to make it work without the tight binding of a `@ViewChild`.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 13 and Angular Material 13, I had to click the "trigger" element for the select.

```
this.mySelect.trigger.nativeElement.click();
```

(Same configuration below as other answers)

In component:

```
@ViewChild("mySelect") mySelect;
```

In template:

```
<mat-select #mySelect ...
```

Comment: It will work, however, this is not the angular way of doing things. I've added an answer on how to properly achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In the .html file you need to add the anchor to the mat-select element:

```
<mat-select #dropdownAnchor></mat-select>
```

And in the .ts file add this:

```
@ViewChild('dropdownAnchor', {static: false}) dropdownAnchor: MatSelect;

openDropdown(): void {
  this.dropdownAnchor.open();
}
```